# ArcGIS javascript api application page shows blank page in Internet Explorer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a ASP.net application from where I send query parameters (using hyperlink) to a ArcGIS javascript application to show query result on map. Now the issue I am having is, when I first send the query parameter, the map displays correctly, but from second time it starts to show blank page. But then if I refresh IE, it shows the map correctly.

Here are some more information.

```
 1) I am sending different query every single time.

 2) It works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome.

 3) I don't get any error in IE console.

 4) I tried using fiddler to monitor and it looks like browser is not doing anything.
```

Has anyone ever encountered this issue?

Comment: What version of IE are you testing with?

Comment: Hi Mintx, I am using IE 11

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check when you get different behaviours in different browsers is the validity of your markup since they treat invalid html very differently. Check the html of your page after the second query parameter using a validator such as https://validator.w3.org/.

If this does not work I would suggest posting the problematic code in your question to allow closer inspection.

Comment: Thanks Jon for your suggestion, I fixed invalid html as you suggested, still not luck, so finally what I did is force reloading the page and that fixed the issue in IE